# More plotting options for pandas.DataFrame.plot(kind="bar")

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

The `pandas.DataFrame.plot(kind='bar')` method is convenient because it plots bars grouped and appropriately colored by the rows and columns of the data frame. For example:

```
timeDf.plot(kind='bar', legend=False)
```

produces

[image]

for the following data frame:

[image]

But what if I want the plot to have, e.g.

- logarithmic y-axis
- labels for the y- and x-axis

The method itself does not seem to have options for that? Is the support for customization so limited or am I missing something?

I hesitate to rebuild this plot function in matplotlib because I expect it to be laborious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `set_scale` and `set_xticklabels` for those:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((6,6)))
ax=df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.yaxis.set_scale('log')
ax.set_xticklabels(['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
```

[image]

If you want the ticks to be evenly spaced, you should do:

```
ax.set_yscale("log", nonposy='clip') #nonposy is required, otherwise the bar disappears.
ax.set_ylim((0.1, 100)) #remember to rest the limit.
```

[image]

Since `matplotlib` 1.3, the `set_scale` method is deprecated and replaced with `_set_scale`

Comment: `ax.yaxis.set_scale("log")` gives a strange result. In my case and also in your example above.

Comment: strange how, exactly?

Comment: @cphlewis The ticks on the y-axis become logarithmic (and the tick labels start to overlap), but the bars are not scaled accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure the ticks on the y-axis are properly logarithmic, even; shouldn't the minor ticks be logarithmically spaced, not evenly spaced between major (labelled) ticks? And until we know what they mean, it's hard to say whether the bars are correctly drawn.

Comment: I know that the bars do not change at all when going from linear to "logarithmic". This means that something is wrong here.

Comment: @cls, I think I know what you want, you want the ticks to be evenly spaced, not log spaced, see edit.